# C#/Java/Ruby - Hash Alogrthym for Passwords - Cross-Lang/Platform

Tags: c#, java, ruby, cross-platform, hash

What is a good password hashing algorithm to use from C#, if later on you may know that there are going to be Java and Ruby programs that may also need to 'login'/authenticate a user. Anything out of the box in .NET that translates well to other languages and is easy to use.

Comment: Ref this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711709/encryption-decryption-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strongest cryptographic hash algorithm which NSA/NIST has standardized on is SHA-512.

Be sure to use a per-password random salt (a 128-bit salt generated by a cryptographically strong random number generator is good). Or, even better, be sure to use a per-password random key (again generated by a cryptorandom), and use HMAC-SHA-512. Be sure to use multiple iterations - 4096 and 65,536 are good round numbers (2^12 and 2^16).

```
let h = get_hash_hunction("SHA-512")
let k = get_key_for_user("Justice")
let hmac = get_hmac(h, k)
let test = get_bytes("utf-8", http_request_params["password"])
for(i in 0 .. (2^16 - 1))
    let test = run_hmac(hmac, test)
return test == get_hashed_password_for_user("Justice")
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct using of MD5 having salt added makes rainbow tables and brute force quite expensive. So, the comment pretty valid to use md5.

Answer (score -1):

A think the MD5 is the most common one.

Comment: MD5 is over-used and too easy to reverse with simple database-driven generators that store the MD5 equivalent of thousands of passwords.