# rails encryption/decryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, openssl

i need to do encryption and decryption in my rails app. Im trying to use ezcrypto, but whenever i do decryption i get this error.

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError in ProfilesController#show

wrong final block length
```

What would need to be changed to stop this error. I tried using another implementation of openssl like this (methods to be called from my model)

```
def encrypt_attr(unencrypted)
    c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
    c.encrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('pass')
    e = c.update(unencrypted)
    e << c.final
    return e
end

def decrypt_attr(encrypted_attr)
  if encrypted_attr != ""
    c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
    c.decrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('pass')
    d = c.update(encrypted_attr)
    d << c.final
    return d
  end
end
```

It throws the exact same error on decryption. How should i do encryption and decryption and not get this openssl error.

Comment: hmm, my bad, you do have the same key in `c.key`

Comment: works for me. I'm getting this error only if `encrypted_attr` != `e` from `encrypt_attr` method. In this case you should use `rescue` in your `decrypt_attr` method

Comment: @jack, out of curiosity, if you are using cipher-block chaining, where is your initialization vector? See 5.3, Initialization Vectors, http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711709/encryption-decryption-in-rails

Answer (score 18):

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

class AesEncryptDecrypt

  KEY = "EncryptDecryptGurudathBN"
  ALGORITHM = 'AES-128-ECB'

  def self.encryption(msg)
    begin
      cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(ALGORITHM)
      cipher.encrypt()
      cipher.key = KEY
      crypt = cipher.update(msg) + cipher.final()
      crypt_string = (Base64.encode64(crypt))
      return crypt_string
    rescue Exception => exc
      puts ("Message for the encryption log file for message #{msg} = #{exc.message}")
    end
  end

  def self.decryption(msg)
    begin
      cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(ALGORITHM)
      cipher.decrypt()
      cipher.key = KEY
      tempkey = Base64.decode64(msg)
      crypt = cipher.update(tempkey)
      crypt << cipher.final()
      return crypt
    rescue Exception => exc
      puts ("Message for the decryption log file for message #{msg} = #{exc.message}")
    end
  end
end
```

#### Encryption

```
irb(main):007:0> AesEncryptDecrypt.encryption('gurudath')
=> "rUPKObydUJd9cY9agm3Glw==\n"
```

#### Decryption

```
irb(main):008:0> AesEncryptDecrypt.decryption('rUPKObydUJd9cY9agm3Glw==')
=> "gurudath"
```

Comment: what is padding mechanism, how to use PKCS5Padding to encrypt data in above program

Comment: Iam using same algorithm but my key is OpenSSL::PKey::RSA type, throwing `no implicit conversion of OpenSSL::PKey::RSA into String` exception when we set key as `cipher.key = KEY`

Comment: Note, [ECB mode is insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946/5328)

Answer (score 2):

I know that the documentation is pretty sparse for Ruby's `openssl` package. However, if you would like to use [cipher-block chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29), here is a brief snippet of code that outlines how to use the `AES-256-CBC` cipher:

```
require 'openssl'

# your data
raw  = 'the data to be encrypted goes here'
pwd  = 'secret'
salt = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(8)

# prepare cipher for encryption
e = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
e.encrypt
# next, generate a PKCS5-based string for your key + initialization vector 
key_iv = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac_sha1(pwd, salt, 2000, e.key_len+e.iv_len)
key = key_iv[0, e.key_len]
iv  = key_iv[e.key_len, e.iv_len]

# now set the key and iv for the encrypting cipher
e.key = key
e.iv  = iv

# encrypt the data!
encrypted = '' << e.update(raw) << e.final
p encrypted

# and now we prepare to decrypt
d = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
d.decrypt
# now set the key and iv for the decrypting cipher
# this assumes that the password, salt, and iv are known,
# so then you would be able to generate the key as per above
d.key = key
d.iv  = iv

# decrypt the data!
decrypted = '' << d.update(encrypted) << d.final
p decrypted
```

This snippet is taken pretty much verbatim from the [Japanese (original?) version of the Ruby standard library documentation on `openssl`](http://doc.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.8.7/class/OpenSSL=3a=3aCipher.html). However, it does raise a few questions for you and your application design:

1. You need to save the `salt` value. This is used along with the password to generate the key (you do not need to save the key).
2. You need to save the `iv` initialization vector. This is used to start the very first block in the cipher-block chain. There is no need to encrypt this value, but this value should be generated for each and every message you encrypt.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and this is how I solved it:

1. Your database column has to be: t.column :data, :binary, :limit => 10.megabyte.
2. Use the exact code as [this blog post](http://www.brentsowers.com/2007/12/aes-encryption-and-decryption-in-ruby.html).
3. Choose AES-256-ECB
4. Leave ivs as nil
5. Choose a long key